# Relation between weak limits

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence, bochner-spaces

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space such that $H\hookrightarrow \hookrightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Let $\{u_n\}$ be a sequence such that $u_n$ converges strongly to $v$ in $C([0,T]; H')$ and converges weakly to u in $L^2((0,T) \times \mathbb{R}^d)$, converges in weak star sense to $u$ in $L^\infty((0,T) ; L^2(\mathbb{R}^d))$. Can we say that $u_n(t)$ converges weakly to $u(t)$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and do we have $u \equiv v$?

We can observe that as evaluation map is continuous, we have strong convergence of $u_n(t) \to v(t)$ in $H'$.

Comment: 1. I don't think you get $u_n(t) \rightharpoonup u(t)$ in $L^2$, since this would imply $u \in C(0,T;L^2)$, which seems far fetched. By typical embedding you get $u \in C_w(0,T;L^2)$, and I doubt you can achieve strong continuity. 2. Yes, $u=v$ is true. On the one hand, you have $u_n \to v$ in $C(0,T;H')$, i.e. $u_n \rightharpoonup v$ in $L^2(0,T;H')$. On the other hand, you have $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $L^2(0,T;L^2)$ and therefore, $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $L^2(0,T;H')$. By the uniqueness of weak limits you have $u=v$.

Comment: How do you get $u\in C(0,T;L^2)$ in the first line and $u \in C_w(0,T; L^2)$ in the second line?

Comment: $C(0,T;H') \cap L^\infty(0,T;L^2) \hookrightarrow C_w(0,T;L^2)$, see the book on the Navier-Stokes equations from Boyer and Fabrie. The limit has to be well-defined, i.e. $u(t) \in L^2$ for all $t$.

Comment: Okay but that says $C_w(0,T;H') \cap L^\infty(0,T;L^2) \hookrightarrow C_w(0,T;L^2)$, here we have $C(0,T;H')$ along with $L^\infty((0,T) ; L^2(\mathbb{R}^d))$. Can't we say better?